# When rotating device the content isnt turning

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello maybe someone can help me, I've got an issue with landscape. I've done the auto layout, but when I actually rotate the device the content isn't turning at all. Anyone knows what to do?

[image: Here's the example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click your project, and go to your iOS target. In the general tab, make sure device orientation is checked for the landscape orientations:

[image: Device Orientation setting]

This change should also be reflected in the `info.plist` file.