# WKWebView - content not rotating on device rotation

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am fairly new to iOS development and I'm using a WKWebView to render my website. But the problem is that on the device rotation, the content is not rotating. I am not sure whether I need to do any settings in my app or any script needs to be added.

Here is the screenshot.

[image: Login Page]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When rotating device the content isnt turning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68627936/when-rotating-device-the-content-isnt-turning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wkwebview is just another webview. I'd say you have to go Target Settings and check all the orientations. That'd do the job

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved my problem.